# a c# service that login any web page

Tags: c#, automation, html

I just want to do a service that automaticly login a web page in start up because our internet provider has a page and we enter our password to access the internet.
it is frequently loged out (I couldn't understand why) I'm bored to rewrite pass many times in a day
how can I do?

thanks for answers...

not: I know windows form app but not service :( it will be fist time for me;)

Answer (score 2):

**A** solution to your problem is Roboform: http://www.roboform.com/

This solution won't require any programming skills.

Comment: I actually know another "type of wheel" that will go 1 step further. On start up, autorun a wget script to authenticate with his service, save the session and inject into browser of your choice as if the browser authenticate with the service.

This however has only been a concept and I have not yet had one successful attemp :(

Comment: I downloaded wget for windows and I can't find how to save session inject to browser
can u explain?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox, there are a lot of greasemonkey user scripts to demonstrate you how to auto-login.